# decimal random number generator

Tags: random, ipython, decimal, spyder

I want to generate a list of like 10 random decimals between say 0.101 and 0.909. At present this seems to work for two decimal places:

```
    for i in range(10):
        print (random.randint(75,95)/100)
```

With an output as follows:

```
0.93
0.8
0.85
0.89
0.89
0.78
0.79
0.91
0.82
0.86
```

I would like this to have 3 decimal places not 2 and I then need to select one of the values and put it into a variable.

Comment: By using randint(750,950)/1000?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I know to do it is like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    print (random.random() * (0.909 - 0.101) + 0.101)
```

How does it work? The general formula for generating a random number from `0` to `B` is this:

```
random.random() * B
```

Because `random.random()` generates a number in the range `[0,1)`, so multiplying that by `B` yields numbers between `[0,B)`. Now, if you don't want to start the resulting range at `0` but at `A`, you do can attempt to write:

```
random.random() * B + A
```

But that yields numbers between `[A,A+B)` which is not what you want, that's why we do the subtraction too:

```
random.random() * (B - A) + A
```

Going step by step:

```
random.random()                -> [0,1)
random.random() * (B - A)      -> [0,B-A)
random.random() * (B - A) + A  -> [A,B)
```

In your case, `A = 0.101` and `B=0.909`. Note that, as the range is open at the right, you will never get exactly `0.909` but you can get `0.90899999` or anything else that is very close.

Finally, about the number of decimal places, check the documentation of the `print` function on how to print numbers up to a certain decimal position (this is different depending on your Python version). For example it could be like this in Python3:

```
print('{0:0.3f}'.format(my_var))
```

Comment: thanks will try what if i want a variable say myvar = float(random.random() * (0.909 - 0.101) + 0.101) to be one of the list ?

Comment: Hi just tried myrand = int(random.random()*(12-8)+12) and it is returning values only above 12 it looks to me like any value above 12-8=4+12 i got one 17 ??? also i tried a simple random.random() and it only returns 0 I thought default was values between 0-10??

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you meant, but `int(random.random()*(12-8)+12)` is not the formula I wrote, it should be `+8` at the end, not `+12`. About the return value fo `random.random()`, if you are only getting the number `0`is because you are casting it to `int`, don't do the casting if you want to see just what that function returns.

Comment: like how do i select on of the decimals from i and cast it to a variable